# Laravel6+ Create Model Dynamically without migrating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

As i Don't know is it possible or not creating a laravel model without migrating it

i am creating a Dynamic db like that :

```
private function createTransactionTable($data) {
        $str = $data->name;
        $name = str_replace(' ', '_', trim($str));
        Schema::connection('mysql')->create($name.'_transaction', function($table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

1. How can i create that related models ?
2. if not possible how can i use a single model for many tables?

Comment: You can call artisan command ```Artisan::call("make:model", ["name"=>$modeName]); ```

Answer (score 0):

Nice to meet you.
First you have to create relation in your Person model

```
class Person extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['firstname', 'lastname'];

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Employee');
    }
}
```

After that in your controller you can do:

```
$person = Person::create($personData);
$person->employee()->create($employeeData);
```

Best regards

Comment: I think u misunderstood my question :(